# Geth returns txhash of sendTransaction() but nothing is broadcasted on Ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, web3-providers, hash, sendtransaction

I have a strange issue with Geth. The code I've written is based on [web3.php](https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php) and worked well up to now. Currently, I'm testing sending ETH via `sendTransaction()` method. The operation finishs and I receive the txhash, but when I browse in in explorer, nothing appears regarding to this transaction!
This is the final result: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x820bdb5d81b8822eee95dee491763df34f24efbf82abc32f4002fbe9765559ba

I don't receive any error while sending transaction, and I got really confused why this problem happens :(
May you help me please?

**Edit1:** this is my code:

```php
$from = 'SenderETHAddress';
$to = 'RecipientETHAddress';
$value = '0x38d7ea4c68000';
$GLOBALS['eth']->sendTransaction(['from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to, 'value'=>$value], function ($err, $data) {
    if ($err !== null) { 
        echo $err->getMessage();
        return;
    } else {
        print_r($data);
        return true;
    }
});
```

And I receive the txhash in result of operation. One of received results was:
`0x820bdb5d81b8822eee95dee491763df34f24efbf82abc32f4002fbe9765559ba`

**Edit2:**
I also tried sendind ETH through Geth itself via its console. I ran:

```
eth.sendTransaction({
   from:'0x33D8A484e113480E37010201BF7569bDCb5fec33',
   to:'0xa96Ce4C161271C797d979017821A278e1481eAfA',
   value: web3.toWei(0.00001, "ether")
})
```

And this was the result:

```
"0x922636876cb53d44933e81eb99b0d67a5067b591779bc83b491c37ddf0cfe178"
```

But again, there is nothing related to this transaction hash on the network!

Comment: There is no transaction in this link!

Comment: I know. This is why I wrote this question.

Comment: `The operation finishes` - how exactly are we supposed to guess what operation you've executed, and how you've executed it?

Comment: I added the code I have, I hope it can help you to know what is the operation.

Comment: What node do you connect your web3 to?

Comment: It is my own one, a light Geth on a private server. It is fully synced as `eth.syncing` returns `false`. Everything else work without any issue.

Comment: @goodvibration, any idea?

Comment: By asking `what node do you connect your web3 to`, I was trying to find out whether it is mainnet or some other network (private on your end or public for testing purpose) that you're connected to. I did not get the answer to that, so I'll just assume that you know what you're doing and that you're indeed connected to mainnet. My assumption would therefore be that your GETH node is still very far from being fully synced. When it finally reaches the current block, your transaction will be added to the blockchain and become visible on Etherscan.

Comment: The chances of some other transaction with the exact same hash being added to the blockchain before yours, are of course negligible.